# Kibana index pattern repeated hits

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, kibana-7

I'm a newbie in elk stack, and now I can't get what I expected in creation of index patterns. Here is the problem:

First, I created a logstash `conf` file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "(?<execution_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (?<execution_time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})%{GREEDYDATA}/configs/pipelines/(?<crawler_category>([^/])+)/(?<crawler_subcategory>([^-])+)-(?<crawler_name>([^.])+).json"]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
        ecs_compatibility => disabled
        index => "log_6"
    }
}
```

Then, I updated this file, `log_6.log`, three times:

- **First:**

`log_6.log`

```
2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/7/subcat7-my_file_7.json)"
```

In kibana's `Discover` option: **one** hit

```
crawler_category:7 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:02:32.968 crawler_subcategory:subcat7 crawler_name:my_file_7 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/7/subcat7-my_file_7.json)" _id:uEvZoHcBZfIv8WwqqBlB _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
```

- **Second:**

`log_6.log`

```
2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/7/subcat7-my_file_7.json)"
2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/8/subcat7-my_file_8.json)"
```

In kibana's `Discover` option: **three** hits

```
crawler_category:7 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:02:32.968 crawler_subcategory:subcat7 crawler_name:my_file_7 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/7/subcat7-my_file_7.json)" _id:uEvZoHcBZfIv8WwqqBlB _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
crawler_category:7 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:04:01.510 crawler_subcategory:subcat7 crawler_name:my_file_7 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/7/subcat7-my_file_7.json)" _id:ukvaoHcBZfIv8Wwq-hrX _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
crawler_category:8 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:04:01.515 crawler_subcategory:subcat7 crawler_name:my_file_8 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/8/subcat7-my_file_8.json)" _id:u0vaoHcBZfIv8Wwq-hrd _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
```

- **Third:**

`log_6.log`

```
2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/7/subcat7-my_file_7.json)"
2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/8/subcat7-my_file_8.json)"
2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/9/subcat9-my_file_9.json)"
```

In kibana's `Discover` option: **five** hits

```
crawler_category:7 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:02:32.968 crawler_subcategory:subcat7 crawler_name:my_file_7 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/7/subcat7-my_file_7.json)" _id:uEvZoHcBZfIv8WwqqBlB _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
crawler_category:7 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:04:01.510 crawler_subcategory:subcat7 crawler_name:my_file_7 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/7/subcat7-my_file_7.json)" _id:ukvaoHcBZfIv8Wwq-hrX _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
crawler_category:8 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:04:01.515 crawler_subcategory:subcat7 crawler_name:my_file_8 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/8/subcat7-my_file_8.json)" _id:u0vaoHcBZfIv8Wwq-hrd _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
crawler_category:9 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:04:33.595 crawler_subcategory:subcat9 crawler_name:my_file_9 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/9/subcat9-my_file_9.json)" _id:PEvboHcBZfIv8WwqeBsm _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
crawler_category:8 host:fe299a799115 execution_date:Jan 12, 2021 @ 21:00:00.000 @version:1 path:/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log @timestamp:Feb 14, 2021 @ 11:04:33.595 crawler_subcategory:subcat7 crawler_name:my_file_8 execution_time:12:41:17 message:2021-01-13 12:41:17,756 luigi-logger[11977] INFO: *****> Chamando "UpdateDBTables(/home/ubuntu/my_folder/my_software/configs/pipelines/8/subcat7-my_file_8.json)" _id:PUvboHcBZfIv8WwqeBsn _type:_doc _index:log_6 _score:0
```

Why each time I update `log_6.log` file with a new log line index pattern gets hits for older entries? For example, why in the third `log` update it reads second line of log again?

**Update:** Here is logstash `log`

```
Attaching to docker-elk_logstash_1
logstash_1       | Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
logstash_1       | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
logstash_1       | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
logstash_1       | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/tmp/jruby-1/jruby2302152547405294616jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
logstash_1       | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
logstash_1       | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
logstash_1       | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
logstash_1       | Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:20,574][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.10.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10 on 11.0.8+10 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:20,651][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:20,667][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:21,471][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"0c9439e7-3c67-4b5d-90f4-a99008772803", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:22,115][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and targeted for removal in the next major version.
logstash_1       | Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at: 
logstash_1       | https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:23,391][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:24,743][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:25,089][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:25,202][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:25,210][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:25,463][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Monitoring License OK
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:25,465][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Validated license for monitoring. Enabling monitoring pipeline.
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:28,676][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 49 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 47 values 
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,562][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,798][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,800][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,881][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,892][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,923][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,924][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,930][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:29,931][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:30,033][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchMonitoring", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:30,059][WARN ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] 'pipeline.ordered' is enabled and is likely less efficient, consider disabling if preserving event order is not necessary
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:30,069][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:30,254][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:30,344][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:30,367][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2, "pipeline.sources"=>["monitoring pipeline"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x524db6c0 run>"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:30,537][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x7719a78e@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:54 run>"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:31,467][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.1}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:31,528][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.98}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:31,575][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:31,904][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_4665540243166de885448baafb9de578", :path=>["/usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log"]}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:31,941][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:32,064][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>2, :running_pipelines=>[:".monitoring-logstash", :main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:32,088][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][1564967280b5861f1e98faa762e5f84d80b5a693bf98ecd54f18d1bcfc26ea2d] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
logstash_1       | [2021-02-14T14:02:32,906][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

**Update 2:** Also, here is my `sincedb` file, after appending the three log lines:

```
18616173 0 2050 486 1613311473.59608 /usr/share/logs_data/log_6.log
18616174 0 2050 324 1613311441.515639
```

If I understood correctly, it is correct, because 324 is the quantity of characters before last file update and 486 is the quantity of characters after the file update.

I also checked the elastic user interface in `localhost` port, for index `log_6`, in `Index Management` session:

[image]

It is saying that 5 as `Docs Count` value, which makes me think if the data is reaching Kibana the right way...

Comment: How are you running logstash? Look in the logstash logs, is there any error or warning? Update your question with the logstash logs when you run logstash and edit the file.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have errors in the log. I updated the post and here is the log

Comment: Also, I'm using the following docker implementation: https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

Comment: Added `sincedb` too, if helps. Is this `sincedb` display correct?

Comment: So, you are editing the file inside the container? How are you doing this? My guess is that the inode is changing when you edit the file and logstash will read from the beginning again, the second line in your sincedb file indicates this also. Try this, instead of editing the file use echo and redirect to the file, `echo "line" >> your-file.log`, you will see that lines are not duplicates because the inode is the same.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you again Leandro =)